# Relation between pullback and fiber product.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Consider the following cartesian diagram of schemes:
$$\begin{array}
AX^{'} & \stackrel{v}{\longrightarrow} & X \\
\downarrow{u} & & \downarrow{f} \\
\mathrm{Spec}A & \stackrel{g}{\longrightarrow} & Y \ .
\end{array}
$$
Let $F$ be a sheaf on $X$. Then It seems that $F \otimes A$ is used in many books of algebraic geometry instead of $v^*F$ . Does $F \otimes A$ means $u^*(f_*F \otimes _ {O_Y} A^{\sim})$ ? In this case, is it canonically isomorphic to $v^*F$ ?

I see that $v^*F$ is isomorphic to $F \otimes A$ in affine case.

Comment: $F\otimes A$ means $v^*F$. This is not the same thing as $u^*(f_*F\otimes_{O_Y} A^\sim)$. Indeed, take $Y=\operatorname{Spec}k$ and $g$ the identity. Take $X=\mathbb{P}^1$. Then $X'=X$ and $v^*F=F$. On the other hand, $u^*(f_*F\otimes_k k)$ is not isomorphic to $F$ in general.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment and the good example.Why do people use the notation $F \otimes A$?

Comment: As you said, this is what $v^*F$ is in the case of affine schemes. More generally, $F$ is locally a module over some ring $B$ and $A$ is a $B$ algebra. Then $v^*F$ is just the extension of scalar of $F$ by $A$ (at least locally). Look at examples, this will be quite explicit.